# OpenGL ES 1.1 on iOS: No clipping planes?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, clipping, opengl-es-1.1

I have an earnest desire to use clipping planes, and I am currently using OpenGL ES 1.1.
In theory I could upgrade to GL ES 2 or 3, I'd simply have to learn a bit more e.g. about shaders.
But is there a way to do clipping planes in GL ES 1.1?

UPDATE:
iOS has 6 planes available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/1.1/es_full_spec_1.1.pdf) OpenGLES 1.1 supports clip planes. You can get the number of supported clip planes with glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_CLIP_PLANES, &iNumClipPlanes). The spec mandates at least 1 clip plane, which may not be sufficient for your needs.

If you're iOS specific, then [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/OpenGLES/Conceptual/OpenGLESHardwarePlatformGuide_iOS/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html) shows that all the old iOS devices have 6 GL_MAX_CLIP_PLANES on OpenGLES 1.1, and I'd be surprised if the newer ones have less.

Alternatively, there are interesting ways to warp your view frustum to get a single clip plane which might help depending on your situation - particularly useful for reflections:

http://hacksoflife.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/every-now-and-then-i-come-across.html

http://www.terathon.com/code/oblique.html